# how to remove " from the attributes and also the index number

Tags: r, feature-selection

```
> wt<-c() 
 braz<-read.csv("braz.csv",header=T)
 index<-1:nrow(braz)
 tindex<-sample(index,trunc(length(index)*.7))
 trainbraz<-braz[tindex,]
 testbraz<-braz[-tindex,]
 weights<-chi.squared(Class~.,trainbraz) 
 wt$v<-weights$attr_importance
 wt$rn<-c(row.names(weights)) 
 a<-wt$rn[wt$v>0]
   >a
 [1] "Word7"   "Word12"  "Word30"  "Word40"  "Word55"  "Word63"  "Word73" 
 [8] "Word75"  "Word76"  "Word77"  "Word91"  "Word92"  "Word105" "Word107"
[15] "Word123" "Word127" "Word129" "Word133" "Word134" "Word151" "Word152"
[22] "Word170" "Word191" "Word199" "Word201" "Word202" "Word207" "Word211"
[29] "Word216" "Word258" "Word272" "Word282" "Word291" "Word333" "Word338"
[36] "Word345" "Word347" "Word379" "Word387" "Word403" "Word421" "Word425"
[43] "Word447" "Word456" "Word468" "Word476" "Word479" "Word487" "Word494"
[50] "Word499" "Word502" "Word511" "Word513" "Word518" "Word519" "Word523"
[57] "Word546" "Word553" "Word561" "Word595" "Word607" "Word608" "Word615"
[64] "Word619" "Word631" "Word650" "Word673" "Word687" "Word691" "Word705"
[71] "Word714" "Word726" "Word731" "Word799" "Word814" "Word815" "Word823"
[78] "Word832" "Word839" "Word851" "Word855"
```

i want to add 5 top attributes form a

```
  subset <- cutoff.k(a, 5)# FSelctor package
  f <- as.simple.formula(subset, "Class")
```

output error are

> subset <- cutoff.k(a, 5)
>          Error in if (dim(attrs)[1] == 0) return(character(0)) : 
>         argument is of length zero
>   f <- as.simple.formula(subset, "Class")
>         Error in paste(attributes, sep = "", collapse = " + ") : 
>          cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

as it looking from error due to "" the addition is not happening. How to remove "" form "Word7" "Word12".."Word855" and so on and retrieve only Word7 Word12 .. Word855
Also how can o remove the index number i.e, [1] [8]....

Comment: You'll need to rewrite your question before anyone can help you rewrite your formula. It's not clear what you want to do, or what packages you're using. The help for `cutoff.k` indicates that `a` needs to be a data frame, not a character vector as you have it: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FSelector/FSelector.pdf

Comment: @Ben i now made everything clear. can you help me now if possible

Comment: @user3821035.  I don't have the `FSelctor` package.  Perhaps, this could help:  Vectorize(as.name)(a) #or lapply(a, as.name)

Comment: @akrun how can i remove all "" from the attributes and store in another variable at a time

Comment: @user3821035. lapply(a,as.name)
[[1]]
Word7 . Your code is not reproducible.  I created a character vector and tried. 

[[2]]
Word12

[[3]]
Word30

[[4]]
Word40
---

Comment: Using this example: a1 <- c("Word7","Word12",  "Word30",  "Word40",  "Word55", "Word63",  "Word73"); lapply(a1, as.name) , I get them as a list.

Comment: i am doing this just to make the as.sample formula work

Comment: > wt<-c()<br/> 
 braz<-read.csv("braz.csv",header=T)<br/>
 index<-1:nrow(braz)<br/>
 tindex<-sample(index,trunc(length(index)*.7))<br/>
 trainbraz<-braz[tindex,]
 testbraz<-braz[-tindex,]
 weights<-chi.squared(Class~.,trainbraz) 
 wt$v<-weights$attr_importance
 wt$rn<-c(row.names(weights)) 
 a<-wt$rn[wt$v>0]
   >a
 [1] "Word7"   "Word12"  "Word30"  "Word40"  "Word55"  "Word63"  "Word73" 
 [8] "Word75"  "Word76"  "Word77"  "Word91"  "Word92"  "Word105" "Word107"